# Why is strncpy in my for loop uneffective?

Tags: c, loops, strncpy

I'm trying to split a string into multiple little strings (of nb size).
But it doesn't work as i would like :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *source = argv[1];
  int taille=0;
  int i=0;
  int k;
  int nb = 5;
  char dest[strlen(source)/nb][nb];
  while(i<strlen(source))
  {
    char *src = &source[i];
    strncpy(dest[taille],src,nb);
    i=i+nb;
    taille++;
  }

    for(k = 0 ; k <8;k++)
  {
    printf("\t%s\n",dest[k]);
  }
}
```

here is the trace :

```
jerome@debian:~/codeFTP/code/serveur$ ./a.out " bonjour cocoman, tu me donne20 balles?"
     bonjour cocoman, tu me donne20 balles?
    our cocoman, tu me donne20 balles?
    ocoman, tu me donne20 balles?
    n, tu me donne20 balles?
     me donne20 balles?
    onne20 balles?
    0 balles?
    les?
```

but the most weird is that if i take out the while ( or thefor, i've tried both), it works ( by takingoff the while i mean writing the strncpy 8 times with appropriates values instead of using loops).
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: How did you compile this code? you should create an array with const size , or should allocate memory for that! in this line:
"char dest[strlen(source)/nb][nb];" 
 when strlen(source) is specifying in run time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strncpy` does not null terminate strings. You'll need to do that yourself. When you printf the first one, printf never finds the null and starts printing off whatever happens to follow it in memory. Because they are in an array, the next byte it sees is the first byte of the next string. This continues until it reaches the last string, which is null terminated because strncpy actually saw the end of the source string.

You'll need to change your declaration to hold one more byte per string for the null character:

```
char dest[strlen(source)/nb][nb + 1];
```

And then manually null-terminate each substring after the copy:

```
dest[taile][nb] = 0;
```

I'm not sure why unrolling the loop worked - there was probably a slight change in your other logic when you rewrote it.

Edited to add: Also, as Gopi said in their answer, your math for finding the number of strings rounds down. If the string length ins't a perfect multiple of nb, then your array is too small and you are invoking undefined behavior. The simplest solution is to add one to that dimension too. Your loop is safe because it is based on strlen, not the number of substrings you computed.

```
char dest[strlen(source)/nb + 1][nb + 1];
```

Comment: seems to work by adding your advices : 

`char dest[strlen(source)/(nb+1)][nb+1]; .....
dest[taille][nb]=NULL;`
thanksa lot

Comment: @Stikmou Pass some string of length less than 5 and you see UB isn't it?

Comment: @Stikmou Not `strlen(source)/(nb+1)` - that's actually worse than before! It needs to be `strlen(source)/nb + 1` which is equivalent to `(strlen(source)/nb) + 1`. @Gopi could you explain the UB on short inputs? I'm not seeing it right now, but I could easily be overlooking something.

Comment: @Katie, I understand my mistake, but why do i need then the '+1'?? i will have "(strlen(source)/nb)" blocks of "nb+1" size (+1 for the null ) right?

Comment: @Stikmou Consider a 12 character source string being broken into 5 character chunks. The result will be 2 5-character strings and a 2-character string (plus nulls), so three total. 12/5 is 2.4, which rounds down to 2, so your array declaration can only hold 2 of those strings. Adding 1 gives you room for three. In cases where it is an exact multiple, you end up with one extra space (15/5+1=4, when you only need 3), but it doesn't seem worth the effort of writing extra code just to save those few bytes.

Comment: @Katie oh i see now, by removing your + 1 i've had a seg error, which confirmed your theory ;) , thanks again for your help

Comment: @Katie Last question, you seem to like my problems ;) would this beright to avoid the filling of the last block with garbage ?:
    `if((i+nb)<strlen(source))
    {
      strncpy(dest[taille],src,nb);
      dest[taille][nb]=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      strncpy(dest[taille],src,strlen(source)%nb);
      dest[taille][strlen(source)%nb]=NULL;
    }`

Comment: @Stikmou You don't need to worry about null-terminating the last one - strncpy will fill the end of the string with nulls if the source string is shorter than the copy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential problem with

`strlen(source)/nb` as index and this will have minimum rows compared to `strlen(source)` and you are doing the below

```
  while(i<strlen(source))
  {
    char *src = &source[i];
    strncpy(dest[taille],src,nb);
    i=i+nb;
    taille++;
  }
```

Now `dest[taille]` is bound to be array out of bound access and also make sure

`strncpy()` doesn't `\0` terminate the strings.

Basic case : Pass some string of length less than 5 and you have UB. There are multiple such potential bugs in your code.